# How to send the form data to controller using REST API and store in database

Tags: html, codeigniter

I have a controller called `Api.php`.

Here I have used `REST API` in codeigniter framework.

How can I send the form details to the `addBook_post` function

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Api extends REST_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
      //  $this->CI->lang->load('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('book_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');

    }

    public function view_get(){
        $this->load->helper('form');    
    }



    //API - client sends isbn and on valid isbn book information is sent back
    function bookByIsbn_get(){

        $isbn  = $this->get('isbn');

        $id  = $this->get('id');

        if(!$isbn && !$id ){

            $this->response("No ISBN OR ID specified", 400);

            exit;
        }
        if($isbn){
            $result = $this->book_model->getbookbyisbn( $isbn );

            if($result){

                $this->response($result, 200); 

                exit;
            }else{

                 $this->response("Invalid ISBN", 404);

                exit;
            }
        }
        if($id){
            $result = $this->book_model->getbookbyid( $id );

            if($result){

                $this->response($result, 200); 

                exit;
            }else{

                 $this->response("Invalid ID", 404);

                exit;
            }

        }
    } 

    //API -  Fetch All books
    function books_get(){

        $result = $this->book_model->getallbooks();

        if($result){

            $this->response($result, 200);
        } 

        else{

            $this->response("No record found", 404);

        }
    }

    //API - create a new book item in database.
    function addBook_post(){

         $name      = $this->post('name');

         $price     = $this->post('price');

         $author    = $this->post('author');

         $category  = $this->post('category');

         $language  = $this->post('language');

         $isbn      = $this->post('isbn');

         $pub_date  = $this->post('publish_date');

         if(!$name || !$price || !$author || !$price || !$isbn || !$category){

                $this->response("Enter complete book information to save", 400);

         }else{

            $result = $this->book_model->add(array("name"=>$name, "price"=>$price, "author"=>$author, "category"=>$category, "language"=>$language, "isbn"=>$isbn, "publish_date"=>$pub_date));

            if($result === 0){

                $this->response("Book information coild not be saved. Try again.", 404);

            }else{

                $this->response("success", 200);  

            }

        }

    }


    //API - update a book 
    function updateBook_put(){

         $name      = $this->put('name');

         $price     = $this->put('price');

         $author    = $this->put('author');

         $category  = $this->put('category');

         $language  = $this->put('language');

         $isbn      = $this->put('isbn');

         $pub_date  = $this->put('publish_date');

         $id        = $this->put('id');

         if(!$name || !$price || !$author || !$price || !$isbn || !$category){

                $this->response("Enter complete book information to save", 400);

         }else{
            $result = $this->book_model->update($id, array("name"=>$name, "price"=>$price, "author"=>$author, "category"=>$category, "language"=>$language, "isbn"=>$isbn, "publish_date"=>$pub_date));

            if($result === 0){

                $this->response("Book information coild not be saved. Try again.", 404);

            }else{

                $this->response("success", 200);  

            }

        }

    }

    //API - delete a book 
    function deleteBook_delete()
    {

        $id  = $this->delete('id');

        if(!$id){

            $this->response("Parameter missing", 404);

        }


        if($this->book_model->delete($id))
        {

            $this->response("Success", 200);

        } 
        else
        {

            $this->response("Failed", 400);

        }

    }


}
```

This is the `Form.php` file.

I want collect the form data and send to `Api.php` file. Any possible ways please let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="">

Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" >
<br>
Price:<br>
<input type="text" name="price" >
<br>
Author:<br>
<input type="text" name="author" >
<br>
Category:<br>
<input type="text" name="category" >
<br>
Language:<br>
<input type="text" name="language" >
<br>
ISBN:<br>
<input type="text" name="isbn" >
<br>
Publish Date:<br>
<input type="text" name="publish_date" >
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>


</body>
</html
```

Comment: Hint:[`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: how to use ajax here to send form data please post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your form action you forgot to place `<form method= "post" action = "<?php base_url('Api/addBook_post');?>">`

Comment: forgot to place what

Comment: if you want to run your ci on your chrome type in ypur url

[link](localhost://foldername/your_controller) or [link](127.0.0.1://ci_foldername/your_controller)

Comment: but form is not submitted to the database it shows unknown method

Answer (score 0):

On your Api controlleR try this:

```
function addBook_post(){

 $this->load->library('form_validation');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'price', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'author', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'category', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('language', 'language', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isbn', 'isbn', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('publish_date', 'publish_date', 'required');

     $name      = $this->post('name');

     $price     = $this->post('price');

     $author    = $this->post('author');

     $category  = $this->post('category');

     $language  = $this->post('language');

     $isbn      = $this->post('isbn');

     $pub_date  = $this->post('publish_date');

     if($this->form_validation->run()){

        if(!$name || !$price || !$author || !$price || !$isbn || !$category){

            $this->response("Enter complete book information to save", 400);

         }else{

            $result = $this->book_model->add(array("name"=>$name, "price"=>$price, "author"=>$author, "category"=>$category, "language"=>$language, "isbn"=>$isbn, "publish_date"=>$pub_date));

            if($result === 0){

                $this->response("Book information coild not be saved. Try again.", 404);

            }else{

                $this->response("success", 200);  

            }

        }

     }else{

        echo 'error';
     }



}
```

I hope this will do. Since you did not post also on what's in your model. This is all i can do for now. For more info about [Active Record](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#insert) click the link.

Comment: model code                                                                                         
                 public function add($data){

        if($this->db->insert('tbl_books', $data)){

           return true;

        }else{

           return false;

        }

    }